# Magento Widgets Truncate Fields Containing Quotes

Tags: php, magento, widget

I'm creating a new widget that allows custom text/HTML to be added to the page. I noticed that **if you enter text containing double-quotes, the first occurrence of it and everything after gets cut off, so that you're missing data when you try to edit the widget again**.

To make sure I didn't screw something up, I was able to verify this issue on a fresh install of Magento (1.7), by adding a stock widget -- Catalog Product Link -- to the page. If you set the `Anchor Custom Text` to something with double-quotes, insert, and edit again, you will see the text has been truncated.

I'm not sure where the problem occurs. The data is successfully written to the tinyMCE content element, but somehow gets malformed between there and an Ajax.Request call for the `admin/widget/loadOptions` route.

I found a related article here:
http://www.behrendt.io/2013/04/12/using-a-wysiwyg-editor-in-a-magento-widget/

The author mentions at the bottom a need for overriding a controller to use base64 encoding when transmitting data for widgets. This seems like it might work for me, but I wanted to be sure.

Here's a visual example of the problem I'm experiencing:

[image: Steps to Re-produce]

Anyone seen this before? Know where it comes from? How to fix? :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like that article put me in the right direction, by overriding `Mage_Widget_Adminhtml_WidgetController`:

http://www.behrendt.io/2013/04/12/using-a-wysiwyg-editor-in-a-magento-widget/

I took his solution a step further and decided to encode ALL values when building the widget code:

```
# Namespace_Module_Adminhtml_WidgetController extends Mage_Widget_Adminhtml_WidgetController
public function buildWidgetAction()
{
    $type   = $this->getRequest()->getPost('widget_type');
    $params     = $this->getRequest()->getPost('parameters', array());
    $asIs   = $this->getRequest()->getPost('as_is');

    if($type == 'namespace/module_widget') 
    {
        foreach($params as $key => $value)
        {
            $params[$key] = base64_encode($value);
        }
    }

    $html = Mage::getSingleton('widget/widget')->getWidgetDeclaration($type, $params, $asIs);

    $this->getResponse()
        ->setBody($html);
}
```

This meant I also had to decode them when loading the widget for editing:

```
# Namespace_Module_Adminhtml_WidgetController extends Mage_Widget_Adminhtml_WidgetController
public function loadOptionsAction()
{
    try {
        $this->loadLayout('empty');

        if( ($paramsJson = $this->getRequest()->getParam('widget')) ) 
        {
            $request = Mage::helper('core')->jsonDecode($paramsJson);

            if(is_array($request)) 
            {
                $optionsBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('wysiwyg_widget.options');

                if(isset($request['widget_type'])) 
                {
                    $optionsBlock->setWidgetType($request['widget_type']);
                }
                if(isset($request['values'])) 
                {
                    if($optionsBlock->getWidgetType() == 'namespace/module_widget')
                    {
                        foreach($request['values'] as $key => $value)
                        {
                            $request['values'][$key] = base64_decode($value);
                        }
                    }

                    $optionsBlock->setWidgetValues($request['values']);
                }
            }

            $this->renderLayout();
        }
    } 
    catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) 
    {
        $result = array('error' => true, 'message' => $e->getMessage());

        $this->getResponse()
            ->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
    }
}
```

And finally, in my widget block, I had to decode all data on-the-fly:

```
# Namespace_Module_Block_Widget
public function getData($key = '', $index = null)
{
    if('' === $key) 
    {
        $data = $this->_data;

        foreach($data as $key => $value)
        {
            if(is_scalar($value))
            {
                $data[$key] = base64_decode($value);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $data = parent::getData($key, $value);

        if(is_scalar($data))
        {
            $data = base64_decode($data);
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
```

It would be nice if a similar encoding mechanism was part of core code.